# How can selenium click a button with a dynamic ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So the following code has ID's for each button but they are dynamic every refresh and I've tried using `maleBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Male"]').click()` however that doesn't seem to select or click the button.

```
    <div id="759f1410-6451-4e18-8ef7-641692381f54" class="gender-buttons gender component">
  <div class="shim"></div>
  <div class="error"></div>
  <label for="27be9dfd-67f6-4fc1-8e7d-cf18edad0b6d">Gender</label>

  <input type="hidden" id="27be9dfd-67f6-4fc1-8e7d-cf18edad0b6d" value="" name="gender" data-componentname="gender">

  <ul data-componentname="gender">
    
      <li id="c5348cb4-3dd3-4841-8bec-d41523d16d11" class="">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Male</span>
      </li>
    
      <li id="fd7b0bd9-0c59-41be-8b5c-fbbe1e97ba9b" class="">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Female</span>
      </li>
    
  </ul>
  <div class="tip">Please select a preference.</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts of making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to click the preceding input tag of male.

```
//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//span[text()='Male']/preceding::input[@type='button']
```

Got the element before but it ran into an overlapping element so I just invoked click directly to the element. Also if you haven't use Webdriver waits to allow the page to load the element properly.

Complete Code:

```
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/ca/register')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
maleBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//span[text()='Male']/preceding::input[@type='button']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", maleBtn)
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

[image: Clicked Element]

Comment: Still doesn't click the button. I've noticed when the button is clicked it says "checked" in the button's class if that helps

Comment: What website is it on?

Comment: when I try the same thing for the JOIN US button, it doesn't work. Is there a way around this? I thought I found the exact button but not sure.

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='JOIN US']"))).click()

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic xpath to click button

//button[contains(text(),'Male')]  try this