# Using Selenium/Robotframework to press a button in a variable form with generic code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, dynamic, robotframework

So our developers recently updated the HTML of our intranet, and now our TestAutomation has problems clicking form buttons such as save/submit, as well as using a reference that can be used througout the testing process.

One such page has a "opslaan" button with the following code:

```
<button id="elgg-field-3pk9yo" type="submit" class="elgg-button elgg-button-submit" data-form-type="action"><span class="elgg-button-label">Opslaan</span></button>
```

Another page has the following code (also with an "Opslaan" button)

```
<button id="elgg-field-ao8hli" type="submit" class="elgg-button elgg-button-submit"><span class="elgg-button-label">Opslaan</span></button>
```

So I have two problems. I used to be able to use a generic reference such as `xpath=//li[@data-menu-item="edit"`]/a, but that no longer works as "opslaan" (edit), cannot be found by Testframework. I could hardcode to the direct part, but that would mean I need to reference about 80 different implementations/locations of this button.

SO I am also looking for a way that gives me a generic code that I can reference to througout my testscript.

I tried [How can selenium click a button with a dynamic ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546174/how-can-selenium-click-a-button-with-a-dynamic-id) and other common variables.

To be honest however I have no prior coding experience and my knowledge goes about as far as creating basic xpaths such as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebtTE.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more examples of the button? Can be there case when several buttons are present?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'generic reference'.
Just in case, if you need just locator help:

1. tag 'button' that has tag 'span' with text 'Opslaan':

   //button[span[text()='Opslaan']]
2. tag 'button' that has aggregated text of all child nodes equal to 'Opslaan'

   //button[.='Opslaan']
3. Probably, you could rely on attribute type='submit', like `//button[@type='submit']` however depends on whether there is only one submit button on the page or not.

Anyway,

> 80 different implementations/locations of this button.

looks very suspicious) I guess the 80 buttons are located on different pages, so probably 'Page Object' design pattern worth looking into. E.g. to have different Opslaan's locators for different pages of your webapplication.